# Qt frames disappears after a while

Tags: c++, qt, frames, invisible

I have done a Windows form application in Qt and I have some QPushButton, QGroupBox and so on and the application is working great.

But when i leave the application to the next day, i see that all frames around buttons, groupboxes and all widgets that have frames dissapears. But the application still working as it should.

[image: How it looks]
Here i have edited a picture how it looks.

Application sets some stylesheets on some widgets in other dialogs, and sets some widget enabled on and off.

But is there anyone that has got same problems? And maybe have an explaining why it happens?

Comment: What it looks like? Is the appearance consistent with the stylesheets in other dialogs?

Comment: You should tell which Windows version you are using (XP, Vista, 7, 8) and telling the exact version of Qt cannot do any harm either. Have you tried running the application in more than one computer?

Comment: Think about a button in old windows style, a button that is gray same as the background, label in the middle and a frame around. The frame is gone, so you just se a label. And the groupbox too, you just see all contents, and the groupbox label at the top. I wich I could share a picture, but I dont have permission yet in Stackoverflow.

I use Windows XP with both old and new styles, several computers and tried to use Qt 4.8.0, 4.8.1 and 4.8.4 but the bug is still there. Now i am running it on a Windows 7, but i haven't got the bug there yet.

Comment: Sharing some of your code might help us debug this issue. How are you creating these buttons and group boxes?

Comment: It is a pretty huge project. But there is only some setStylesheet() and setEnabled() somewhere. BUT! I maybe have an explanation. I updated Windows XP from service pack 1, to the latest and no more graphics bugs!! And the bugs don't appears on Windows 7. I will test run it more and if no bugs appears then i will take it as an Answer.

Comment: Did the update fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, your program leak GDI Objects.

A windows application can only use 9999 GDI Objects.
when your application leak too many GDI Objects, your application will looks look as your picture.

You can press Ctrl+Shift+Esc to see how many GDI Objects your application used.